# Power set recursive, generating sets for more than 3 elements.

Tags: java, recursion, set

I am creating a recursive algo to be able to take n then from there creating power sets.  I mean, if 3 is entered a power set of {{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}}.  At the moment, my algo only works up until 3 but in a way it is hardcoded, also the last SOP line prints out 1,2,3,}}.  I can't seem to figure out how to implement it recursively for more than 3 elements.

```
Public static void main(String[]args){


        int elements = 0;
        while(elements!=-1){
            System.out.println("What's the number of elements? ");
            elements=   scan.nextInt();
            if(elements==-1){
                System.out.println("Terminate. ");
                break;
            }
            System.out.print("{");
            lab5(elements,0);
            System.out.print("}" );
            System.out.print("}");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
static void lab5(int a,int b){
        String cur = "{";
        String curBack = "}";

        if(a==0){
            System.out.print(cur+curBack);
        }
        else if(a>0){

            System.out.print(cur+a+curBack);
            String phrase = null;
            b = a-1;
            if(a==b){
                b=a-2;
            }
            phrase = cur+a+", "+b+curBack;//a problem might be 

            b = a-2;
            if(b==0){
                phrase = "";
            }

            if(a==b){
                b=a-2;
            }

            System.out.print(phrase);
    lab5(a-1,b);
System.out.print(a+",");
```

Comment: `b = a-1;
            if(a==b){
                b=a-2;
            }` , huh ...

Comment: That was only to skip the pair of set.  i.e. {2,2}, instead it'll be {2,1}, it backfires when it goes to 0 or -1 tho.

Comment: That condition will never be true, anyway, your way of doing this ( even for 3 ) doesn't look good, And this is not how you should use recursion. Recursion in this case would be useful if you  calculate the sets for 2, ({1},{2},{1,2}). and then the sets for 3 would be those sets union those sets where you add 3 to each sub set (even the empty subset to have {3})

Comment: Yup honestly, I had figured that it wasn't good.  I am going to be taking a different approach (going to use linked list) to be able to accomplish the power set.